# Multi-Level Multi-Table Aggregate Calculation with CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables from which I need to add an aggregate (sum(totalcost) to a column from another table.  I also need to calculate the total cost in order to add or subtract based upon the line number in yet another table.  Finally,  I need to identify the item type for the order as the final condition for the aggregate

```
Order table

Order Num    Material Cost   Service Cost  Total Cost
11111         200.00           220.00        210.00
11112           0.00             0.00          0.00

OrderCost Table
Order Num    Costline     Cost       Purchase Order ID    % of PO Cost
11111           1         100.00       P00001               50%
11111           1         110.00       P00002               50%
11112           2         100.00       P00001               50%
11112           2         110.00       P00002               50%

OrderDetails Table
Order       ItemReq    ItemType    Cost
11111       M10001      MATERIAL   200.00
11111       S10001      SERVICE    220.00
```

When an order is added to the OrdeCost table,  the following is required:

1. The aggregated Material Cost by Order ID
2. The aggregated Service cost by Order ID
3. Need to subtract the material cost from the OrderDetail Material Cost for the existing record
4. Need to subtract the service cost from the OrderDetail Service Cost for the existing record
5. Need to add the aggregate material costs to the result from order ids that are not in the OrderDetail table
6. Need to add the aggregate service costs to the result from order ids that are not in the OrderDetail Table

**Result**

```
Order ID   TotMatCost     TotServCost     TotCost
11111       100.00         110.00          210.00
11112       100.00         110.00          210.00
```

Modified code just a bit

```
select order.wonum, order.wopriority, order.worktype, order.estintlabcost,order.estoutlabcost, order.estlabcost,
order.estmatcost, order.estservcost, order.esttoolcost, order.actintlabcost, order.actoutlabcost, order.actlabcost,
order.actmatcost-
(select sum(loadedcost)*
(CASE costlinenum
  WHEN 1 THEN 1
  ELSE -1 END) NUMLINES
from cost, OrdedetalisL
where cost.cc_wonum = Ordedetalisl.wonum and Ordedetalisl.linetype = 'MATERIAL'
 AND cost.percentage<100 and cost.cc_wonum = 'H1006'
group by cc_wonum, costlinenum) actmatcost,
order.actservcost-
(select sum(loadedcost)*
(CASE costlinenum
  WHEN 1 THEN 1
  ELSE -1 END) NUMLINES
from cost, WPSERVICE
where cost.cc_wonum = wpservice.wonum and wpservice.linetype = 'SERVICE'
 AND cost.percentage<100 and cost.cc_wonum = 'H1006'
group by cc_wonum, costlinenum) actservcost, order.acttoolcost,(order.estintlabcost + order.estoutlabcost + order.estlabcost+order.estmatcost + order.estservcost + order.esttoolcost  +
order.actintlabcost + order.actoutlabcost +
(select sum(loadedcost)*
(CASE costlinenum
  WHEN 1 THEN -1
  ELSE 1 END) NUMLINES
from cost
 where percentage<100 and cc_wonum = 'H1006'
group by cc_wonum, costlinenum)) totalcost
from order where order.wonum = 'H1006'
```

Comment: did you try to write some code already? show us if you did

Comment: Saying what you need isn't a question.   What is your question about this?   What part of this do you not know how to do?

Comment: The code is something like this but it returns too many values

Comment: The code works until I add a third row to an Order in the OrderCost table.  Then the query errors with too many values from the CASE portions of the statement.  Working on CTE now as another option